# Gps lat & long randomly displays very inaccurate results

Tags: java, android, gps

Im listening to my phones GPS and post latitude and longitude to my webservice evey time `onLocationChanged` gets called. My problem is that in about 2% of my posts, it displays a VERY inaccurate result (several miles off). Should i check the accuracy from my `location` object before i post? Or do you have any other suggestions? Thanks!

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(networkLocationListener);

    textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + "New GPS location: "
            + String.format("%9.6f", location.getLatitude()) + ", "
            + String.format("%9.6f", location.getLongitude()) + "\n");

    //float accuracy = location.getAccuracy(); check this value?

    postLocationToWebservice(location);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common problem while using the Location services of Android.There are few checks you can introduce to make sure that only the  accurate location gets posted to you web service.

1.Compare the accuracy of all the location services.

2.Define a minimum limit for accuracy and a maximum limit for time.(Because some times the location obtained is accurate but it is an old one).

Check this code snippet and make necessary changes to accomplish what you want.Make sure you make a 
log build that  checks the accuracy of your algorithm.

```
List<String> matchingProviders = myLocation.lm.getAllProviders();
    for (String provider: matchingProviders) 
    {
        Location location = myLocation.lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (location != null) {
            float accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
            long time = location.getTime();

            if ((time > minTime && accuracy < bestAccuracy)) {
                bestResult = location;
                bestAccuracy = accuracy;
                bestTime = time;
            }
            else if (time < minTime && bestAccuracy == Float.MAX_VALUE && time > bestTime) {
                bestResult = location;
                bestTime = time;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Followup question: Could you give me an example on how to post the time as a long? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that the updated location is reported by `NETWORK_PROVIDER` instead of `GPS_PROVIDER`

you can always get the last updated GPS location by

```
     mLocationMgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```